# How to test the eq of a .rjust 8, "0" with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a little function to make a customer_nr with

```
id.to_s.rjust 8, "0"
```

This gives me a 8 diget number with the id and before filled with `0` until I have 8 diggets.

How can I test this with rspec? The first test works, but the second on is wrong since the id is interactive. Any Idea how to test the eq? FactoryGirl creates a user with `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`. This works if the created user gets an single digget id.
When it gets a more diggets id then the test fails.

Like `expected: "00000002398" got: "00002398"`

```
describe "#customer_nr" do
      it "should have 8 digits" do
        user.customer_nr.length.should eq 8
      end

      it "should use the user_id" do
        user.customer_nr.should eq "0000000#{user.id}"
      end
    end
```

best regard
denym

Comment: what do you have when you run this test?? something like: "should be 00000008 but got..."

Comment: edit question for further explaination

Comment: Why you don't just test that `customer_nr` is equal to `id.to_s.rjust(8, '0')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my comment and your edit issue is easy. Everything is correct but your user have id 2398. You can make test in irb

```
2398.to_s.rjust 8, "0"
```

give exactly what test return. In test your db created records and destroy after tested but id still increment. You can make:

```
user.customer_nr.should eq "0000000#{user.id}".split(//).last(8).join
```

or like toro2k wrote in his comment.